# Is there a way to Automatically check in pending changes TFS 2018

Tags: tfs

This is my requirement.

1. I have a project that reference three DLLS from third party.
2. These dll's change. So I would like to get them checked in automatically without having to perform any manual task such as having to press the check in button in Visual Studio.

Once it is checked in TFS CI will take over make and build and run the tests.

My environment is TFS 2018 and Visual Studio 2017-2019.

I have spent enormous amount of time. trying to figure this out.

Comment: Hi, what have you tried? Can you share a bit? Are you using git or TFS version control?

Comment: I have been trying TFSVC. Since this is what we use in TFS 2018.

Comment: Have you tried the TFS command line "status" https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/tfvc/status-command?view=azure-devops

Comment: I had a look at that, but I think I have to run an application manually to do the check in. I want check in to be done as soon as there is a pending change. Without any manual intervention.

Comment: I am afraid this cannot be achieved.  You have to manually check in the pending changes.

Comment: This is an X-Y problem. You shouldn't be putting binaries in source control. Put them in an artifacts feed.

Answer (score -1):

You can schedule [tf checkin](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/tfvc/checkin-command?view=azure-devops) as a windows task. It can run every 10 mins or 1 hour the following command:

> tf checkin /noprompt "PATH_TO_LOCAL_WORKSPACE_FOLDER" /recursive

If `PATH_TO_LOCAL_WORKSPACE_FOLDER` does not have changes, the command returns:

> There are no pending changes matching the specified items.

> No files checked in.

If the folder contains changes, the command check-ins, and returns:

> The list with some files
>
> Changeset #ID checked in.